# How do I export a .tmx file into a custom format?

Tags: maps, tilemap, file-format

I just created a map in [tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org) software. The problem is that it has created a .tmx file. But I need a different format than that, something I can easily store in 2D `int` array.

By 2D `int` array I mean:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

0 = sky
1 = ground
2 = tree
```

How do I go about converting the .tmx file into this format?

Comment: The docs suggest that the maps are already easily parsed, and that the work has already been done to implement it.  https://github.com/bjorn/tiled/wiki/Support-for-TMX-maps

Comment: Also: https://github.com/bjorn/tiled/wiki/TMX-Map-Format (It already is text.  It's xml.)

Answer (score 1):

Converting a file from one format to another isn't too hard if you have [decent documentation](https://github.com/bjorn/tiled/wiki/TMX-Map-Format) on both formats (or you're making up your own target format). Luckily, Tiled has some software that [is available](https://code.google.com/p/tmx-parser/) for it that allows you to easily read .tmx files. To convert, follow these basic steps:

1. Read the current format
2. Process the data read into some intermediate state
3. Write the intermediate state into the new format

You can skip step 2 if you don't need to do any rearranging or complex changes and just write directly to the new format from the current format.

First you'll want to learn more about the existing format, so you know what you're reading. Then make a set of rules for converting the existing format into your new format. For example, when you see a land tile, you'll write a `1` to your new file.

It's sometimes a tedious process. You may want to explore your rationale for converting the files in the first place. .tmx files are [widely supported](https://github.com/bjorn/tiled/wiki/Support-for-TMX-maps), and you might want to stick with that standard and choose a different data structure than a `int` array for storing your map.

Comment: ah ok i see so i need to create a rules.txt file which will have all the rules to format the xml file. i tried looking at documentation but had hard time understanding it. is there examples online?

Comment: Examples of what? You have the only example you need with the file you've created.

Comment: I am new to game programming and i have no idea what you guys are saying. can some one plz just help me out. what do i put in rules.txt file?

Comment: There's no rules.txt file. The misunderstanding goes both ways. You might want to learn a bit more about programming in general before continuing. Then, I suggest you try a more discussion oriented site if you're having trouble understanding. This site isn't really for discussions. See the [bottom of this page](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details on where to ask.

Comment: ok got it. but before i leave, just answer me this. do i need to download another software to convert tmx file to 2d int array format?

Comment: No. You're going to write it.